# Plotly R : Format axis tick labels to log10

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I am creating line charts in plotly using `plotly::ggplotly()` with x and y-axis representing `log10` values.

Is there a way to display x and y-axis tick labels as `log10`?

I have tried using `tickformat = ".1r"` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                   labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
     scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                   labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))

p <- plotly::ggplotly(p)

p <- p %>% layout(
           yaxis = list( 
                 tickformat=".1r"
                 ),
           xaxis = list(
                 tickformat=".1r"
                )
         )
p
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use something like superscripts in ggplot, you use commands like `expression`. When the data was sent through `ggplotly`, so was `expression.

If you wanted the axes labeled like the ggplot graph, you can remove the command `expression` and replace the `^` with `<sup></sup>` from the `ggplotly` object. However, for the y axes, the values aren't rounded, so I've shown you the literal result, the object `valy`. Then I rounded them in `valy2`. That way, whatever you were looking for might already be here.

I used `p1`, not `p` for the Plotly object.

Later in this answer, I'm going to show you what `.1r` will give you, which is unlikely what you were looking for.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(scales)

set.seed(23)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 1000000, 39999),
                  y = rnorm(100, 99999999999, 111111))
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
    scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
p1 <- plotly::ggplotly(p)

valx <- p1$x$layout$xaxis$ticktext %>% 
  toString() %>% str_split(", ") %>%  # <---- that's a comma and whitespace
  unlist() %>% str_replace("\\^(.*)$", "<sup>\\1</sup>")    
valy <- p1$x$layout$yaxis$ticktext %>% 
  toString() %>% str_split(", ") %>%  # <---- that's a comma and whitespace
  unlist() %>% str_replace("\\^(.*)$", "<sup>\\1</sup>")
valy
# [1] "10<sup>10.999999</sup>"  "10<sup>10.9999995</sup>" "10<sup>11</sup>"        
# [4] "10<sup>11.0000005</sup>" "10<sup>11.000001</sup>"  
valy2 <- p1$x$layout$yaxis$ticktext %>% 
  toString() %>% str_split(", ") %>%  # <---- that's a comma and whitespace
  unlist() %>% str_replace("\\^(.*)", "<sup>\\1</sup>") %>% 
  str_replace("(\\...).*(</sup>)", "\\1\\2") # wow, just didn't want to do it in one...
# [1] "10<sup>10.99</sup>" "10<sup>10.99</sup>" "10<sup>11</sup>"    "10<sup>11.00</sup>"
# [5] "10<sup>11.00</sup>" 

p1$x$layout$xaxis$ticktext <- valx
p1$x$layout$yaxis$ticktext <- valy2
p1
```

[image]

Now to show you other ways that would work for formatting text if you started in Plotly.

`e` on the x-axis and `r` on the y-axis

```
plot_ly(df1, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(type = "log", tickformat = ".1e"),
         yaxis = list(type = "log", tickformat = ".1r"))
```

[image]

`~s` on the x-axis and `y` on the y-axis

```
plot_ly(df1, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(type = "log", tickformat = "~s"),
         yaxis = list(type = "log", tickformat = ".1y"))
```

[image]